# Problems using FORMATFILE with BULK INSERT - Converting numerics

Tags: sql-server

Trying to use BULK INSERT with SQL Server.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AA
(
    AA_ID       int identity    NOT NULL,
    B_ID            int             NOT NULL,
    QUALITY_CODE      nvarchar(4),
    VALUE_NUM         numeric(18,4)
)
```

A FORMATFILE like this:

```
10.0
3
1       SQLINT              0       0     "\t"   2     B_ID             ""
2       SQLNCHAR            0       0     "\t"   3     QUALITY_CODE     Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLNUMERIC          0       0     "\r\n"   4     VALUE_NUM      ""
```

and a data file like this:

```
6   OK  50.0000
6   OK  49.0000
6   OK  1023.0000
6   OK  340.0000
```

When I issue this statement:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.AA
FROM 'C:/path/aa.dat'
WITH (  FORMATFILE = 'C:/path/aa.fmt')
```

I get this error:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid data for type "numeric"(SQL-42000) [state was 42000 now 01000]
```

- I have checked that my data file has CR LF line endings.
- I have checked that my data file has tab characters between each field.

I cannot work out what is going wrong.

My code and files are here: https://github.com/rjattrill/MsSql_BulkInsertExample

Comment: is your server column order correct with value 2,4,5? it suppose to be 2,3,4 right ? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes - that was definitely wrong.  But then another error parsing numerics.   I have updated the post.

Comment: check the host  file data length, it not suppose to be zero right ?

Comment: Zero should work as 'no limit'.  I have now fixed the problem by specifying SQLFLT8 as the data type - and will update the answer.   Thank you ah_hau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best approach was to import most things as VARCHAR using OPENROWSET and then allow INSERT to cast automatically.   The built-in datatype conversion with the bulk utilities look to be poorly documented and difficult to use.  It feels easier to import most things as VARCHAR with SELECT FROM OPENROWSET and then allow the built in DML capabilities to cast at the INSERT stage - but possibly at the cost of some performance.

Here is an updated format file:

```
10.0
4
1       SQLINT              0       0     "\t"   2     B_ID             ""
2       SQLCHAR            0       0     "\t"   3     PERIOD_START     Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR            0       0     "\t"   4     QUALITY_CODE     Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR          0       0     "\r\n"   5     VALUE_NUM      ""
```

And code to use it:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AA (B_ID, PERIOD_START, QUALITY_CODE, VALUE_NUM)
SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'C:/src_github/MsSql_BulkInsertExample/aa.dat',
FORMATFILE = 'C:/src_github/MsSql_BulkInsertExample/aa.fmt',
FIRSTROW = 1
) as a
```

Full example here: https://github.com/rjattrill/MsSql_BulkInsertExample